# Question about notation with differential one-form

Tags: differential-topology

Let $M$ be a manifold. The *differential* of $f \in C^\infty(M)$ is defined as the one-form $df$ such that $(df)(v) = v(f)$ for every tangent vector $v$ to $M$.

It is then stated that if $f \in C^\infty(M)$ and $h \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, then $d(h(f)) = h^\prime(f)\,df$. I don't know what this notation means. Will someone please write it down more precisely (see comments)?

**Edit:** Using the regular definition of the differential, we have 
$$d(h \circ f)_m(v) = dh_{f(m)} \circ df_m(v) = dh_{f(m)}\left(v(f)\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{f(m)}\right) = v(f)h^\prime(f(m)),$$
and then writing $v(f) = df_m(v)$ gives the result. However, I'm not sure why it is appropriate to use two different definitions of the differential in the same equation.

Comment: It's the composition of the derivative $h'$ and $f$. Just use the chain rule.

Comment: The...derivative? :P It looks like classical chain rule, doesn't it?

Comment: So the equation is $d(h\circ f)_p = h^\prime(f(p))\,df_p$? I'm not sure about that, because $df_p,\,d(h \circ f)_p : T_p M \to \mathbb{R}$ but $h^\prime(f(p)) \in T_{h(f(p))}\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well, $h'(f(p )) ∈ ℝ$ :) What do you mean two different definitions?

Comment: By which I mean $dh_{f(p)}$ is multiplication by $h'(f(p))$, so $dh_{f(p)} (df_p(v)) = h'(f(p)) df_p(v)$

Comment: Randy Randerson, $T_{h(f(p))}ℝ$  it is identified with ℝ.